# AngularJS: Component and dependence injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have following module:

```
angular.module("individual-footprint")
        .controller("individualFootprintController", individualFootprintController)
        .value("currentUser");
```

controller for this module:

```
 function individualFootprintController($http, individualFootprintService, currentUser) {
        var self = this;
        $http.get("/user").success(function (data) {
            if (data.name) {
                currentUser = data;
                self.authenticated = true;
            }
        })
```

And following component:

```
angular.module("individual-footprint")
        .component('employeeInfoComponent', {
            template:'Logged in as: <span ng-bind="$ctrl.user"></span>',
            controller: function (currentUser) {
                if (currentUser.name) {
                    self.user = currentUser.name;
                }
            }
        });
```

My html is following:

```
<div ng-controller="individualFootprintController as $ctrl">
     <div ng-hide="$ctrl.authenticated">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        With Corporate Account: <a href="/login/corporate">click here</a>
     </div>
     <div ng-show="$ctrl.authenticated" >
         <employee-info-component></employee-info-component>
     </div>
```

Sorry, I am new to AngularJS, and probably I misuse something. My assumption is `.value("currentUser");` is global variable, I can inject it and change it wherever I want. But I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. Could you, please, suggest better solution for my global var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a value as `{}`(empty object) for your `currentUser` value variable. Currently you are doing `currentUser.name` inside component controller where you are trying to access `name` property from `undefined` variable since it throws an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

```
.controller("individualFootprintController", individualFootprintController)
.value("currentUser", {}); //value currentUser defined as blank object
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I see that code of component invokes before code of `individualFootprintController` can I somehow control ordering?

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ could you show me your HTML? how you are arranged it on HTML?

Comment: Sir, I edited my question, I would like `$http.get` request be sent after login, and component controller processed after `individualFootprintController` to obtain initialized `currentUser`

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ just change `ng-show` to `ng-if`, that's it. It will only load `employee-info-component` whenever require. the sequence got automatically maintain

Comment: Thank you! Also my mistake was `currentUser = data;` in documentation about values is written: `Note: Make sure that you never overwrite the value service/object as a whole otherwise your assignment is lost. Always reassign the property values of the value object. The following assignment is wrong and does not lead to the expected behavior`